# Vuejs hiding style tag from head | Laravel-vuejs application

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am working with laravel-vuejs application. When vuejs renders css, then it appends some style tags in the html head like below image. Is there any way to hide this tags. I think it is possible using webpack.conf in vuejs by adding some plugin like, copy-webpack, extra-text-ebpack, optimize-css-assets-webpack etc. but how to do it in larave-vue application.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use extractVueStyles in laravel-mix

> extractVueStyles: Extract .vue component styling (CSS within 
>   tags) to a dedicated file, rather than inlining it into the HTML.

[Laravel Mix Options](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/options)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might write `CSS` in each `Vue` single file component,like this:

```
 //test.vue
  <template>
    <div></div>
  </template>
  <style>
     div{
        //...
     }
  </style>
```

Why not write these `CSS` in a `CSS` file and then require it in `main.js`?then you need't to think about removing these `style` tags.

Comment: Yes. I have written. Still if I avoid writing this way, this will not solve the problems. Cause the packages are appending styles like that way. Also, writing css in extra file flle and require it in main.js is not the actual way. The scope will not work in that way.